# No source repositories were detected at 'path'. Please check the URL and try again

Tags: github, repository, open-source

I am trying to automatically import some open source project to one of my repositories.I am getting the following error:
[image: error screenshot]

Few Queries:

1. If it is possible to import project repositories from popular open source sample project into your own repositories?(Not owned by you).
2. If possible, How to do that ?or Best way to import repositories automatically on your github without downloading repositories and then uploading it?
3. Also,how to automatically update repositories if new  samples projects have been updated?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You have to choose one of these projects, go to their project page and find out the repository URL. Many of them are already on Github, then you can just clone it there. See for example https://github.com/google/vogon

Comment: @Thilo what about those projects which are not available on Github?

Comment: @Thilo do i need to go on each project page for including all the sample project ?is it  not possible to import all project in single repo?

Comment: If you want to use the Github importer web page, you have to import one repo into one repo. It does not combine multiple. But it can import from non-Github git repos, and even from SVN.